# Set of all affine maps between two polytopes

Tags: affine-geometry, polytopes

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space, let $P, Q \subseteq V$ be polytopes with $P \subseteq Q$. (Let a polytope be defined as the convex hull of finitely many points.) I'm interested in the following

**Question:** How can I identify the set of all affine maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ with $T(P) \subseteq Q$?

More precisely, I want to find a "nice" way to characterize the set of all maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ with the following properties:

- $T(\alpha v_1 + (1-\alpha) v_2) = \alpha T(v_1) + (1-\alpha) T(v_2) \quad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \forall v_1, v_2 \in V$,
- $v \in P \Rightarrow T(v) \in Q$.

Admittedly, the question of how to find a "nice" way to characterize this set is rather vague. My motivation for this question is that I have given two such polytopes and want to study this set of maps, and it seems to me that this set is generic enough that people might have studied it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the extreme points of $P$, namely $\operatorname{xtr}(P)=\{p_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{I}}$,then define

$$
\mathfrak{T}\triangleq \{T:V\to V : T(z)=Az+b, Ap_i+b\in Q\}
$$

But, you can also make use of support functions saying that $TP\subseteq Q$ if and only if $\delta^\star(x\mid TP)\leq\delta^\star(x\mid Q)$, where $\delta^\star(x\mid P)\triangleq\sup_{p\in P}\langle x,p\rangle$.

Define the Minkowski functional of a set $C$ as $\pi(x\mid C)\triangleq\inf\{\lambda>0: x\in\lambda C\}$. If $P$ contains the origin in its interior and it is absorbing (i.e., for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a $\lambda$ so that $\lambda P \ni x$) and if you know the extreme points of $Q$, say $\operatorname{xtr}(Q)=\{q_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{J}}$, then $TP\subseteq Q$ iff $\pi(q_i\mid TP)\geq 1$. You can further work to this direction making use of dual polytopes. For a polytope $X$, its dual is the polytope defined as $X^\star\triangleq \{x^\star: \langle x,x^\star\rangle\leq 1, \forall x\in X\}$. Then you can prove that $\pi(x\mid X)=\inf\{\langle x, x^\star\rangle,x^\star\in X^\star\}$.

If your polytopes have a more favourable structure, like $K\mathcal{B}_\infty$ or $K\mathcal{B}_1$, then you can derive simpler expressions from the above properties.

I have asked here a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513513/polytopes-inside-polytopes) in which I provide some criteria for polytopes being subsets of other polytopes.